# Lore Jockey players

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, problem-players, problem-gm

I've been having problems with a player where he'll trying to get me to homebrew rules for him based on these lore points. Recently he wanted to get his blade serrated to do bleed damage. After researching I found that wounding does bleed damage per round based on the amount of successful hits they've got on the creature. I brought this to the player and we calculated the cost. (I think it was somewhere around 18k gp, if I did it right becuase it's a dagger and the wounding adds a +2 to its cost.)

But then he brings up like a line, "can't the back smith just serrate it himself", I pull a line, maybe they can't do that just yet technologically do with out breaking the weapon. Then he gave me a line like, "but the dwarves have the goblin ripper that was super small serrations". How would I handle a player that that I have to abide by lore that he's read in from the dnd lore books? (this may be my fault as I set the campaign in the sword coast so I don't have to make a new world for them to run around in)

Comment: Does this Goblin Ripper weapon apply bleed damage? Because if it doesn't, then why would adding serrations to his dagger work?

Answer (score 17):

"Serrated edges and other aspects of normal weapons are included in the 1d4 slashing hitpoint damage that a dagger does inherently.  A well made dagger, which may include dwarven-made serrations or other aspects, is considered Masterwork - being considerably more difficult to make, and more expensive, and granting +1 to hit (increasing the chance it does damage)."

What your player is doing is called **arguing for advantage**.  It is not really related to pre-existing setting lore at all - this particular argument for example is at least partially related to real-world history, or at least common misconceptions about real-world history (serrated edges on edged weapons).

Your player wants to gain a mechanical advantage in order to succeed more and is attempting to do so by exerting social pressure.  On you directly, or via convincing other players.  This is generally solved in a few ways, the most common of which is just to say 'no'.  As the GM you have authority over the game and the rules used in the game.  If you just repeatedly say no to his attempts to ask for homebrew that favours him, preferably while saying yes to more reasonable suggestions from other players (to provide a comparison to him of the kind of thing that is more acceptable to ask for) (like a player asking if the town has an inn, you say yes - or a church of pelor - or if a blacksmith can forge together his broken sword, or his ranger can roll survival to know whether dragons eat carrion etc), arguing for advantage players will typically rein it in, since their goal (of gaining advantage) is not being met.

You can also discuss it out of game with them.  Or explain to the entire table that you're going to be running the rules as they are and not modify them based on what people consider 'lore' or 'realistic' unless you decide to do so on your own.  There's a myriad of ways to deal with what is effectively a social problem with someone treating the game as 'they have to win' rather than 'a fun thing to do with friends'.

However viewing this as some kind of thing it isn't will generally stop you dealing with it.  Regardless of what is claimed about lore or whatever, this is someone trying to use social arguing to gain advantage in a game, and if you approach the problem from that angle, you will generally quickly see how to resolve it.

I would recommend not simply handing out bonuses to this player any time they say 'but my sword has a hilt guard so I should chop off the orc warlord's fingers' or whatever.  Rarely are such players happy with a situation that doesn't have them wildly overshadowing the party and often such arguing for advantage both takes people out of any roleplaying or storytelling that is occurring and at the same time lowers their investment in the game and bores them.  You generally don't want any of that to happen if you are the GM, and it doesn't particularly add anything to the game if this guy gets 1d2 bleed damage because of his serrated dagger and +5 to scent checks because he cleared his sinuses with lemon juice or whatever.  Just say no.

---

I'm going to add an explaining note to clarify that **this kind of behaviour is not necessarily malicious**.  It can be, but that depends almost entirely on context, intent, and attitude.  *There are a lot of games out there*, both ttrpg and otherwise, where you do need to scrape and scrounge for any and every kind of advantage in order to succeed.  There are a lot of games out there where every player is explicitly competing against each other even if they are theoretically cooperating.  There are a lot of GMs that explicitly encourage arguing for advantage, or treat guessing what favour to ask for as an interesting or required part of the game.

People can be doing this for all sorts of reasons.

It not being malicious doesn't mean it'll be easy to resolve, as misunderstandings can be pernicious or weird or cause confusion or affront.

But if you harbour the attitude that anyone doing things for advantage is 'an evil munchkin' or the like, you'll likely end up exacerbating what could be a quite innocent misunderstanding and make the situation worse, rather than better.  The ideal resolution is a group of people having fun, after all.  The goal is to remove whatever is causing people to have less fun, and assumptions about intent can be corrosive to that process.

Comment: "Cleared his sinuses with lemon juice". That sounds both painful *and* counter-productive, just the kind of thing I'd expect from these kinds of munchkins.

Comment: I solved the issue with him before posting the question, but wanted some imput from more experienced GMs. Thank you. He usually doesn't try to do this stuff unless I'm using a lore heavy world like Sword coast